# PySimpleGui error: Layout has a FUNCTION instead of an ELEMENT

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

after an update of pysimplegui package, every time i try to run a script i get the same error as in the subject.

For example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [[sg.Text('this is a try')]]
window = sg.Window('mytitle', layout)
```

When i run the code the window is created but then a popup tell me:
"Error creating window layout
Layout has a FUNCTION instead of an ELEMENT
this likely means you are missing () from your layout" 
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLEYK.jpg)
and then the window is empty.
This happens with every script, while until this morning before the update everithing was running fine,
I've tried to downgrade the install but now the same error occours with every version

Comment: What version of Python are you running?  I suggest logging it as an issue on GitHub

Comment: hi, i'm running 3.7.3. I'll do as you suggest, thx

Comment: Very odd.  I don't have 3.7 installed with tkinter, but do have 3.8.  It works fine with 3.6 and 3.8.  The only way this can be happening is if there's a problem with type checking in 3.7.  It'll help having the issue filed as it asks for more data like the OS, the version of PySimpleGUI, etc.

Comment: it work with conda-python 3.7.3

Comment: got python 3.7.3, not working, same error